# Applying 'vector' of functions on a Matlab matrix

Tags: function, matlab, vectorization

Let's say I've got a matrix with n columns, and I've got n different functions.
Is it possible to apply i-th function per each element in i-th column efficiently, that is without using loop?
For example for the following variables:

```
funs = @(x) [x, cos(x), x.^2]

A = [1 0 1
     2 0 2
     3 0 3
     4 0 4] ;
```

I would like to obtain the following result:

```
B = [1 1 1
     2 1 4
     3 1 9
     4 1 16] ;
```

without looping through columns...

Comment: Sure, you can do `funs = @(x) [x(:,1), cos(x(:,2), x(:,3).^2]` But then, using an anonymous function would be pointless because vectorization would give you the same result.

Comment: @beaker Thank you but it's not completely what I was asking for. How can I automate this approach for an arbitrary number of functions without refering to the indices of matrix column?
I am thinking about some equivalent of bsxfun(fun, A,B) with fun being a vector of anonymous functions applied row- or column-wise to a matrix. but I can't find any solution of this kind...

Comment: I don't know of a function that does what you're asking for. Is a loop not working for you? That's probably the best solution. One suggestion though, I'd put the functions as individual function handles in a cell array. That'll make referring to them easier.

Comment: Of course loop was the first thing that came to my mind and I will probably use it after all. I know that Mathworks has put some effort to make loops faster, but I wondered if I could apply any vectorization trick of this kind to gain some time improvements.
It's just another time when I miss it over the past few years, so I want to make sure if it exists...